# Rayleigh Quotient and eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

It says in my script: For $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

$$|\mu-R_A(x)| \leq 2\|A\|_2\|v-x\|_2 \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n, \|x\|_2=1$$
in which $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is an eigenvalue and $v,\|v\|_2=1$ its eigenvector.
Futhermore the Rayleigh-quotient is $R_A(x)=\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$.

It says the proof is pretty easy, but I don´t know how to start.. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try $\mu = v^T \mu v = v^T Av$ and use the triangle inequality.

Comment: @psl2Z Thanks for your answer, now I got:
$|\mu-R_A(X)|=|\mu-\frac{x^TAx}{\|x\|_2}|=|v^t\mu v-x^tAx|=|\langle v,Av \rangle-\langle x,Ax\rangle|=|\langle A(v-x),x+v\rangle|\leq \|A\|_2\|v-x\|_2\|v+x\|_2$
But I don´t know how to get $2\|A\|_2$..

Comment: Just use the triangle inequality again and $||v||_2 = ||x||_2 = 1$

Comment: Oh of course.. thank you very much!!!